# In C, sizeof operator returns 8 bytes when passing 2.5m but 4 bytes when passing 1.25m * 2

Tags: c, sizeof

I do not understand why the `sizeof` operator is producing the following results:

```
sizeof( 2500000000 ) // => 8 (8 bytes).
```

... it returns 8, and when I do the following:

```
sizeof( 1250000000 * 2 ) // => 4 (4 bytes).
```

... it returns 4, rather than 8 (which is what I expected). Can someone clarify how `sizeof` determines the size of an expression (or data type) and why in my specific case this is occurring?

My best guess is that the `sizeof` operator is a compile-time operator.

**Bounty Question:** Is there a run time operator that can evaluate these expressions and produce my expected output (without casting)?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3579361

Comment: `sizeof` is for types, not literals, and is evaluated at compile time - why do you need to do this?

Comment: @RogerRowland what do you mean `sizeof` is not for literals?

Comment: @LuchianGrigore - I mean normally it's used to determine the size of some `struct` or array, just wondering if the OP is confusing it with finding the number of bits in an int, for example.

Comment: Also very similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5537276/why-sizeof13-33-is-8-bytes except with integers instead of floats.

Comment: `sizeof` can be used on a type or on an expression.  The literals are expressions; they are fine.

Comment: @RogerRowland it's actually common practice, and recommended, to apply `sizeof` to actual objects rather than classes.

Comment: Is there anyway to determine the memory allocated on runtime? I want to see that 1,5b * 2 is an 8 byte datatype (ie long) at runtime.

Comment: @JacobPollack no, it's not. 1,5b * 2 is undefined behavior at runtime.

Comment: I have updated the original post to be more much clear and concise towards the problem set for future viewers.

Comment: @RogerRowland: `size_t size = sizeof(some_array) / sizeof(some_array[0])` is preferable to `size_t size = sizeof(some_array) / sizeof(array_type)` because, if the type of the array changes, your code isn't suddenly broken. So no, `sizeof` is not "for types, not literals".

Comment: The key point is that (in most cases) C expressions are evaluated independently of the context in which they appear. The type of `1250000000` is the same regardless of whether it's part of `1250000000 * 2` or not.

Comment: @KeithThompson, is there any way to determine the size of an evaluated expression at run time? Is there any way to put it in some sort of "boundless" temporary memory to see the amount of bytes required to store the result of some arithmetic operation. What I asked for is likely not technically right, but does a feature like that exist in C99?

Comment: @JacobPollack: The "authoritative reference" is Section 6.5.3.4.2, "The `sizeof` operator yields the size (in bytes) of its operand, which may be an expression or the parenthesized name of a type". In your second case, the operand is an expression of type `int`, `int` takes up 4 bytes on your system, so it yields `4`. There doesn't seem anything here more complicated than that. The type will be `int` "at run time", too.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths, (+1) I understand that now (from the answers below as well) -- the reason I opened up the bounty was for my follow-up question. I'll make it more clear in my original post (editing now).

Comment: @JacobPollack: Except for variable-length arrays, every expression's size is determined at compile time. I think what you're asking is, for example, given `int x = foo; int y = bar;`, how big an integer type (or which integer type) do you need to store the result of multiplying `x` by `y` without overflow. There's no straightforward way do to that; C pretty much leaves that up to you.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths, I'll make a new question as you suggested. I did not want to risk being flagged as duplicate, that's why I made a bounty to see if anyone is willing to edit an existing reply to include that follow-up.

Comment: @KeithThompson, Makes more sense now, thanks for that. Post it as a follow-up and I will give you the bounty (but the accepted answer stays with Luchian).

Comment: @JacobPollack: As far as I know, you can't give a bounty to someone who hasn't posted an answer.

Comment: @KeithThompson, oh ok. Well thank you non the less for the clarification. I'll award the bounty in 23 hours to another answer if it's revised (as I must wait until a change is made).

Comment: if you aren't interested in C++ and are focused on C please remove the C++ tag

Comment: @JacobPollack If you want to know if an integer multiplication a*b overflows, you might test if INT_MAX/a > b; but beware of the details of signed integer division, and border cases. It's tricky to do this reliably and portably for all values of a and b.

Answer (score 123, accepted):

`2500000000` doesn't fit in an `int`, so the compiler correctly interprets it as a `long` (or `long long`, or a type where it fits). `1250000000` does, and so does `2`. The parameter to `sizeof` **isn't evaluated**, so the compiler can't possibly know that the multiplication doesn't fit in an `int`, and so returns the size of an `int`.

Also, even if the parameter was evaluated, you'd likely get an overflow (and undefined behavior), but probably still resulting in `4`.

Here:

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    long long x = 1250000000 * 2;
    std::cout << x;
}
```

can you guess the output? If you think it's `2500000000`, you'd be wrong. The type of the expression `1250000000 * 2` is `int`, because the operands are `int` and `int` and multiplication isn't automagically promoted to a larger data type if it doesn't fit.

http://ideone.com/4Adf97

So here, gcc says it's `-1794967296`, but it's undefined behavior, so that could be any number. This number does fit into an `int`.

In addition, if you cast one of the operands to the expected type (much like you cast integers when dividing if you're looking for a non-integer result), you'll see this working:

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    long long x = (long long)1250000000 * 2;
    std::cout << x;
}
```

yields the correct `2500000000`.

Comment: Yes, for VC++, MSDN says that an expression is not evaluated - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4s7x1k91(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: @RogerRowland most importantly, the standard says the operand of `sizeof` is not evaluated.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore i didn't get how sizeof of expression2 is 4? [new user]

Comment: Yea so I get that sizeof is evaluated at compile time. Is there anyway to determine the amount of memory given to an expression on run time?

Comment: @Dineshkumar the expression's type is `int` even though the actual result of the expression doesn't fit in one.

Comment: @JacobPollack the amount of memory is the same (4) even if it overflows. If you expect it to overflow, use a `long long` to start off with. Or a big number class.

Comment: You can know what size is required to hold any int if you know the internal representation (almost always 2s complement), so use a sized int like u_int32 or u_int64.  No need to ask the compiler.

Comment: @xaxxon how would the internal representation help to determine the size of the result of an expression that leads to undefined behavior?

Comment: @LuchianGrigore, he is just referring to that the totally dominant way to represent integers today is with 2s complement, and so from there you can know how large numbers a uint32_t can represent. (For instance.)

Comment: Instead of casting, better add an `LL` suffix.

Comment: @Oberon ha I see what you did there!

Comment: @LuchianGrigore What Prof Falken said.  You don't need sizeof() at all to determine what type to use to represent a specific number, you can just figure it out ahead of time for yourself with some basic binary math.

Comment: I am looking for someone to cite the C99 standard for me. This is still a fantastic answer though and if no one does I will re-accept this. If you could cite a C99 standard too then I will give you the bounty and re-accept it.

Comment: @JacobPollack: From the C11 standard, section 6.5.3.4, `sizeof`: "If the type of the operand is a variable length array type, the operand is evaluated; otherwise, the operand is not evaluated and the result is an integer constant."

Answer (score 8):

[Edit: I did not notice, initially, that this was posted as both C and C++.  I'm answering only with respect to C.]

Answering your followup question, "Is there anyway to determine the amount of memory allocated to an expression or variable at run time?": well, not exactly.  The problem is that this is not a very well formed question.

"Expressions", in C-the-language (as opposed to some specific implementation), don't actually use *any* memory.  (Specific implementations need some code and/or data memory to hold calculations, depending on how many results will fit into CPU registers and so on.)  If an expression result is not stashed away in a variable, it simply vanishes (and the compiler can often omit the run-time code to calculate the never-saved result).  The language doesn't give you a way to ask about something it doesn't assume exists, i.e., storage space for expressions.

Variables, on the other hand, do occupy storage (memory).  The declaration for a variable tells the compiler how much storage to set aside.  Except for C99's Variable Length Arrays, though, the storage required is determined purely at *compile* time, not at run time.  This is why `sizeof x` is generally a constant-expression: the compiler can (and in fact must) determine the value of `sizeof x` at compile time.

C99's VLAs are a special exception to the rule:

```
void f(int n) {
    char buf[n];
    ...
}
```

The storage required for `buf` is not (in general) something the compiler can find at compile time, so `sizeof buf` is not a compile-time constant.  In this case, `buf` actually is allocated at run time and its size is only determined then.  So `sizeof buf` *is* a runtime-computed expression.

For most cases, though, everything is sized up front, at compile time, and if an expression overflows at run-time, the behavior is undefined, implementation-defined, or well-defined depending on the type.  Signed integer overflow, as in 2.5 billion multiplied by 2, when `INT_MAX` is just a little over 2.7 billion, results in "undefined behavior".  Unsigned integers do modular arithmetic and thus allow you to calculate in GF(2<sup>k</sup>).

If you want to make sure some calculation cannot overflow, that's something you have to calculate yourself, at run time.  This is a big part of what makes multiprecision libraries (like gmp) hard to write in C—it's usually a lot easier, as well as faster, to code big parts of that in assembly and take advantage of known properties of the CPU (like overflow flags, or double-wide result-register-pairs).

Comment: Interesting, didn't know C99 sizeof evaluates arrays at runtime. +1

Comment: not all arrays, I don't believe, just ones where it can't determine the size at compile time -- where it has a variable length.

Comment: @xaxxon: correct, only VLAs result in run-time work for `sizeof`.

Answer (score 6):

Luchian answered it already. Just for complete it..

C11 Standard states (C++ standard has similar lines) that the type of an integer literal with no suffix to designating the type is dertermined as follows:

**From 6.4.4 Constants (**[C11 draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf)**):**

> Semantics
>
> 4 The value of a decimal constant is computed base 10; that of an
>   octal constant, base 8;  that of a hexadecimal constant, base 16. The
>   lexically first digit is the most significant.
>
> **5 The type of an integer constant is the first of the corresponding
>    list in which its value can be represented.**

And the table is as follows:

Decimal Constant

```
int
int long int 
long long int
```

Octal or Hexadecimal Constant

```
int
unsigned int
long int
unsigned long int
long long int
unsigned long long int
```

For Octal and Hexadecimal constants, even unsigned types are possible. So depending on your platform whichever in the above list (*int or long int or long long int*) fits *first* (in the order) will be the type of integer literal.

Comment: I really wonder what the compiler did, though, when it saw a keyword it thought it was supposed to handle immediately and replace with a constant value, but then saw an expression inside.  I would expect that it would either, 1: fail to compile 2: do the math for some limited subset of expressions or 3: move to a runtime implementation of sizeof (which is apparently used for dynamic array sizes where the size is passed in as a parameter int foo[3*n+1]; sizeof(foo); in which case the multiplication would have been executed.

Comment: Except VLAs, compiler has the size information for types. So it can determine whether an integer literal will fit in in one of the types available.As torek said in his answer, compiler is required to evaluate the operand of sizeof in case of C99 VLAs. (Btw, VLAs are made optional in C11). But compile time evaluation of size
is more straight forward than that.

Comment: I am not sure how it exactly compiler calculates the type. For example, gcc issues a wanring for sizeof(9999999999999999999): `warning: integer constant is too large for long type`. I don't know exactly working of compiler how it determines the size for literals. But it checks: 1. Whether the literal has any suffix designating the type. If so, use that type to fit in. For example, `sizeof(1L)` will be the `sizeof(long)` even though literal `1` will fit in an int.

Comment: 2. If no suffix, then follow the above order starting from int to find the size. 3. If nothing literal is too large to fit any of the types then issue a diagnostic.

Comment: It's nice to cite from the C11 standard (which is in this case virtually identical to the C99 standard), but since many C programmers use either GCC or a compiler that aims to be compatible with GCC, it should be pointed out that by default, GCC does not use the list of types you cite, but instead the C90 list extended at the end with larger non-standard types: http://blog.frama-c.com/index.php?post/2012/01/20/Constants-quiz

Comment: @PascalCuoq `long long` is available since C99. So I would disregard the compling with "gcc t.c" (what standard this code comply with?) as gcc normally includes many non-standard extensions. C99 (and C11) requires the said order to be used for determing types of literals and "-0x80000000" can be represented in an `int` type (INT_MIN is just that on my system), it should have printed -2147483648. (I have reproduced the same with gcc 4.7.3). It certainly appears to be a case of gcc not satisfying C99's requirement. [continued]

Comment: Strangely, it appears the issue is seen only with `long long l;` For example, if I use `int l;` or `long l;`, I get the correct output (-2147483648). Since `-2147483648` can be stored in `int`, the type of `l` shouldn't have mattered in any of the cases.

Comment: If you use `int l;` you get the correct value through an overflow. `-2147483648` is parsed by GCC as unary minus applied to an `unsigned long` (actual result `2147483648`) and this value is converted to `int` when assigned to `l`. Upon conversion, the value becomes `-2147483648`.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I seem to forget this thing that 2147483648 overflows int ;-) But nevertheless `long` should appears to work correctly as said in my previous comment.

Answer (score 2):

Another way to put the answer is to say that what is relevant to `sizeof` is not the value of the expression but it's type. `sizeof` returns the memory size for a type that can be provided either explicitely as a type or as an expression. In this case the compiler will compute this type at compile time *without* actually computing the expression (following known rules, for instance if you call a function, the resulting type is the type of the returned value).

As other poster stated there is an exception for variable length array (whose type size is only known at run time).

In other word you usually write things like `sizeof(type)` or `sizeof expression` where expression is an L-Value. Expression is almost never a complex computing (like the stupid example of calling a function above) : it would be useless anyway as it is not evaluated.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    struct Stype {
            int a;
    } svar;
    printf("size=%d\n", sizeof(struct Stype));
    printf("size=%d\n", sizeof svar);
    printf("size=%d\n", sizeof svar.a);
    printf("size=%d\n", sizeof(int));
```

}

Also notice that as sizeof is a language keyword, not a function parenthesis are not necessary before the trailing expression (we have the same kind of rule for return keyword).

Answer (score 2):

For your follow-up question, there's no "operator", and there's no difference between the "compile time" size of an expression, and the "run time" size.

If you want to know if a given type can hold the result you're looking for, you can always try something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

int main(void) {
    int a = 1250000000;
    int b = 2;

    if ( (INT_MAX / (double) b) > a ) {
        printf("int is big enough for %d * %d\n", a, b);
    } else {
        printf("int is not big enough for %d * %d\n", a, b);
    }

    if ( (LONG_MAX / (double) b) > a ) {
        printf("long is big enough for %d * %d\n", a, b);
    } else {
        printf("long is not big enough for %d * %d\n", a, b);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

and a (slightly) more general solution, just for larks:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

/* 'gssim' is 'get size of signed integral multiplication */

size_t gssim(long long a, long long b);
int same_sign(long long a, long long b);

int main(void) {
    printf("size required for 127 * 1 is %zu\n", gssim(127, 1));
    printf("size required for 128 * 1 is %zu\n", gssim(128, 1));
    printf("size required for 129 * 1 is %zu\n", gssim(129, 1));
    printf("size required for 127 * -1 is %zu\n", gssim(127, -1));
    printf("size required for 128 * -1 is %zu\n", gssim(128, -1));
    printf("size required for 129 * -1 is %zu\n", gssim(129, -1));
    printf("size required for 32766 * 1 is %zu\n", gssim(32766, 1));
    printf("size required for 32767 * 1 is %zu\n", gssim(32767, 1));
    printf("size required for 32768 * 1 is %zu\n", gssim(32768, 1));
    printf("size required for -32767 * 1 is %zu\n", gssim(-32767, 1));
    printf("size required for -32768 * 1 is %zu\n", gssim(-32768, 1));
    printf("size required for -32769 * 1 is %zu\n", gssim(-32769, 1));
    printf("size required for 1000000000 * 2 is %zu\n", gssim(1000000000, 2));
    printf("size required for 1250000000 * 2 is %zu\n", gssim(1250000000, 2));

    return 0;
}

size_t gssim(long long a, long long b) {
    size_t ret_size;
    if ( same_sign(a, b) ) {
        if ( (CHAR_MAX / (long double) b) >= a ) {
            ret_size = 1;
        } else if ( (SHRT_MAX / (long double) b) >= a ) {
            ret_size = sizeof(short);
        } else if ( (INT_MAX / (long double) b) >= a ) {
            ret_size = sizeof(int);
        } else if ( (LONG_MAX / (long double) b) >= a ) {
            ret_size = sizeof(long);
        } else if ( (LLONG_MAX / (long double) b) >= a ) {
            ret_size = sizeof(long long);
        } else {
            ret_size = 0;
        }
    } else {
        if ( (SCHAR_MIN / (long double) llabs(b)) <= -llabs(a) ) {
            ret_size = 1;
        } else if ( (SHRT_MIN / (long double) llabs(b)) <= -llabs(a) ) {
            ret_size = sizeof(short);
        } else if ( (INT_MIN / (long double) llabs(b)) <= -llabs(a) ) {
            ret_size = sizeof(int);
        } else if ( (LONG_MIN / (long double) llabs(b)) <= -llabs(a) ) {
            ret_size = sizeof(long);
        } else if ( (LLONG_MIN / (long double) llabs(b)) <= -llabs(a) ) {
            ret_size = sizeof(long long);
        } else {
            ret_size = 0;
        }
    }
    return ret_size;
}

int same_sign(long long a, long long b) {
    if ( (a >= 0 && b >= 0) || (a <= 0 && b <= 0) ) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

which, on my system, outputs:

```
size required for 127 * 1 is 1
size required for 128 * 1 is 2
size required for 129 * 1 is 2
size required for 127 * -1 is 1
size required for 128 * -1 is 1
size required for 129 * -1 is 2
size required for 32766 * 1 is 2
size required for 32767 * 1 is 2
size required for 32768 * 1 is 4
size required for -32767 * 1 is 2
size required for -32768 * 1 is 2
size required for -32769 * 1 is 4
size required for 1000000000 * 2 is 4
size required for 1250000000 * 2 is 8
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, sizeof() doesn't calculate the memory required for the result of that multiplication.

In the second case both literals : `1250000000` and `2` each requires `4 bytes` of memory, hence sizeof() returns `4`. If one of the values was above `4294967295 (2^32 - 1)`, you would have got `8`.

But i don't know how sizeof() returned `8` for `2500000000`. It returns `4` on my VS2012 compiler

Comment: 2,5b is a long that's why. Is there anyway to determine the amount of memory allocated to an expression or variable at run time?

Comment: @JacobPollack I already answered that. The expression `1250000000 * 2` has 4 bytes allocated to it if used in a context where allocation is necessary. And the result of the expression isn't `2500000000`.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore I know. If 4 bytes is allocated, it will just overflow and give some ambiguous 4 byte integer. Thanks man.

Comment: The maximum possible 4 byte value is 4294967295. Then how come 2500000000, which is below that, requires 8 bytes memory???

Comment: 2500m is a long, ie 8 bytes.

Comment: @AravindMeppallil The signed Integer range is -2147483648 to 2147483647. The unsigned range is 0 to 4294967295. :)

Comment: @Apocalyp5e - Yes! that was my mistake. But, anyway VC compiler is saying `4294967295` and hence `2500000000` which is lower occupies 4bytes and `4294967296` (2^32) occpies 8bytes. So then this compiler might be treating literals as UINT right? :)

Answer (score 0):

The C11 Draft is here:  http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf
You can find the Cx0 draft here:  http://c0x.coding-guidelines.com/6.5.3.4.html

In both cases, section 6.5.3.4 is what you are looking for.  Basically, your problem boils down to this:

```
// Example 1:
long long x = 2500000000;
int size = sizeof(x); // returns 8

// Example 2:
int x = 1250000000;
int y = 2;
int size = sizeof(x * y); // returns 4
```

In example 1, you have a `long long` (8 bytes), so it returns 8.  In example 2, you have an `int * int` which returns an `int`, which is 4 bytes (so it returns 4).

To answer your bounty question:  Yes and no.  `sizeof` will not calculate the size needed for the operation you are trying to perform, but it will tell you the size of the results if you perform the operation with the proper labels:

```
long long x = 1250000000;
int y = 2;
int size = sizeof(x * y); // returns 8

// Alternatively
int size = sizeof(1250000000LL * 2); // returns 8
```

You have to tell it you are dealing with a large number or it will assume it is dealing with the smallest type it can (which in this case is `int`).

Answer (score 0):

The most simple answer in one line is:

**sizeof() is a function evaluated at COMPILE TIME who's input is a c type, the value of which is completely ignored**

FURTHER DETAIL: ..therefore as 2500000000 is compiled it would have to be stored as a LONG as it is too long to fit in an int, therefore this argument is simply compiled as  '(type) long'. However, 1250000000 and 2 both fit in type 'int' therefore that is the type passed to sizeof, since the resulting value is never stored as because the compiler simply is interested in the type, the multiplication is never evaluated.